# Tweet Hash Tags

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone explain to me how Hash tags get anchors after being posted. I want to work on a similar implementation in php. The logic behind that operation and links will be useful. thanks

Comment: What does *ancors* mean?

Comment: <a href ="">#bbc</a> something like this .. i mean how do hash tags become links ? do u add the ancor tag before inserting into db or after reading .. if can explain the whole concept i'll appreciate

Comment: He probably means anchors. (Hyper)links, `<a href="anchor goal">anchor text</a>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$html = preg_replace("/#([a-z0-9_]+)/", '<a href="hashtag/${1}">#${1}</a>', htmlspecialchars($tweet_contents));
```

Comment: does that mean its added b4 data is inserted into db  ?

Comment: @Josh to keep the amount of data stored to a minimum, the anchors are not stored in the db. Instead every time the tweet is loaded the anchor is created using something like what Charlie suggested.

Comment: thanks JLevett thanx Charlie and thanks to every one who contributed. xoxo

Answer (score 0):

something like http://www.snipe.net/2009/09/php-twitter-clickable-links/